2sxc - error in local installation (copy of live instance) something missing?
We have got a 'live' dnn 9.13.2 installation with 2sxc 17.9 which is working without problems. I made a copy of this installation to use as a local dev environment.
And when I try to login on this environment I get an error. I think it might be related to the skin which is based on 2shine:
DotNetNuke.Web.DependencyInjectionInitialize - Unable to configure services for ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.StartUp.StartupDnn9, see exception for details
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ToSic.Sxc.Code.Generate, Version=17.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.
File name: 'ToSic.Sxc.Code.Generate, Version=17.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.StartUp.DnnDi.RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.StartUp.StartupDnn9.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\StartUp\StartupDnn9.cs:line 28
   at DotNetNuke.Web.DependencyInjectionInitialize.ConfigureAllStartupServices(IServiceCollection services)

Any idea why the live site does not have a problem, while the dev environment doesn't?
I've checked the bin folder, but there is no difference between live and dev. So a missing file does not seem the problem.
Also tried to set the rights in IIS again, but that does not seem to be the problem.
What am I missing?

It seems to have trouble loading ToSic.Sxc.Code.Generate at startup. My main guess is something is blocking it, maybe an anti-virus or something?

I saw in another installation in the bin folder it has a file called "ToSic.Sxc.Code.Generate.dll" while in other dnn installations it doesn't.
Both installations are running 17.9 and are working... I made a local copy of the one without the file, and on my local machine it gives the error. On the server it works fine without the dll. Very strange...

Btw. we just changed some content type names and now I needed to change all my code to use the same names. So I think it is kind-of-confusing, the way it is presented on the Data tab. So you have the columns Id, Content Type, ...., Name, Description
So under Content Type it shows the label, and under Name it shows well..., the name.
I would have guessed that it would be the other way around.  So 'Content type' would be the thing to use in queries etc. and name would be a nice label kind of thing for end users...

The dll is the one which generates code files eg. AppCode/Data/MyType.Generated.cs

Btw. I most cases when I upgraded to 17.9 I needed to register the site/2sxc on the patron site. In this case it does not give the warning, and I can go on unregistered.

The patrons unique key is based on dnn/2sxc versions, system name and db name. if they don't change, the registration kind of remains valid.

If you completely cloned a live and working DNN instance to a local dev environment, I recommend you take a close look at what versions of .NET and related items you have installed.
It sounds like the ToSic.Sxc.Code.Generate.dll is failing to load with a missing dependency and the error is not "bubbling up." So, since its obviously outside the DNN instance...
I would focus on trying to make sure you have runtimes installed for .NET Frame work 4.7.x and 4.8.x and run Windows updates to make sure everything is up to date. Then do the same for .NET 6 and .NET 8 (core, modern .NET).
If the problem still exists, try installing the various (matching versions) of the development SDKs next.
.NET Framework Runtimes
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework
All .NET downloads
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet
All .NET 8 SDKs
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0
If that still doesn't work, then digging deeper and finding the real error probably needs more effort.
Another possibility might be that the permissions aren't right for the DLL?
How are you making the copy? Maybe if we had more details about how you cloned the site, there would be a new clue? Have you tried doing a backup (live) and restore (local dev) using a tool like Evotiva DNNBackup?

Two quick things: 1) you should move that "Answer" to a Comment on my Answer. 2) If my Answer worked for you, you should "Accept" the answer, which will then give it a green check-mark. :)

Thanks Jeremy,
Looks like I missed this file in some way.
When I add it it is working.

Two quick things: 1) you should move that "Answer" to a Comment on my Answer. 2) If my Answer worked for you, you should "Accept" the answer, which will then give it a green check-mark. :)
